# Can I have a scalar property in EF 3.5 point to a function in the database for it's value?

Tags: entity-framework

Is it possible to have the data for a scalar property in an entity come from a function?

An example is, I have a field in my database that points is a numerical field, but that means nothing to the user, so I want to add another property, but have it point to a function that returns a meaningful name.

I don't want to add this extra field to the table, so I would rather just add it to the model and right now I am doing it through a view, but I would rather not add views to the model.

Also, if I add this property and update my model from the database, will the added property go away?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this, but I am using Code-First and am using custom providers in WCF Data Services.  So YMMV.  When I build up my metadata, I say that a particular property (`ResourceProperty`) has `CanReflectOnInstanceTypeProperty` set to `false`.  When your query is executed, you will have to modify your Expression tree to replace the instances of `DataServiceProviderMethods.GetValue` and `DataServiceProviderMethods.GetSequenceValue` with your own Expression.  You can do this via an `ExpressionVisitor` class.

This is tricky, but far from impossible.

There were a couple of resources that I found tremendously useful...

This series of blog posts on [data service providers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx).

This series by Vitek about [data service expressions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vitek/archive/2010/02/25/data-services-expressions-part-1-intro.aspx) (in particular, part 4 on typed and untyped properties).

I hope you find this useful...